# How to download image asynchronously using cache and display in tableviewcell in objective-C?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I am trying to download image asynchronously using cache and display in tableviewcell in objective-C. Image is coming from URL. I have written API calling using NSSession and doing background calling using GCD but in this case image is downloading again again while scrolling. I want to image download only once.

```
 //------------ using GCD ---------
        if(![imageUrlString isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]){

                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
                  NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]];
                    if ( data == nil )
                        return;
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        // WARNING: is the cell still using the same data by this point??
                        cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData: data];
                    });
                });
        }
        //------------ using GCD -----
```

For same cashing is only way? if yes please suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: why not use SDWebImage? (https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage)

Answer (score 0):

In development we don't take hassle if we have proper tools and library.Because we have to spend more time in this regard.

[SDWebimage](https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage) is a great library to fulfill your requirement. You don't have to think about all cases. It's already been done for you.

As an example:

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: "your domain name"), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

You just have to write this line in cellForRowAtIndexPath. :)
There are also lots of features in this library.
Happy coding.

Comment: have you read https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/blob/master/Docs/HowToUse.md

Comment: Can you suggest for this error -  UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Comment: Open the "Build Settings" tab, in the "Linking" section, locate the "Other Linker Flags" setting and add the "-ObjC" flag.try this

Comment: And in link binary binary with libraries, add the SDWebImage.a file.

Comment: giving error as -- ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/LION_2/Desktop/Telstra/build/Debug-iphoneos/SDWebImage'
ld: library not found for -lSDWebImage
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145838/discussion-between-elk-cloner-and-sss).

Answer (score 0):

Try SDWedImage

```
[[SDWebImageManager sharedManager]downloadImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl] options:0 progress:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, BOOL finished, NSURL *imageURL) {
    cell.imageView.image =  image; // if you want resize your image and any other operation can do here.
        }];
```

**OR**

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageurl]
             placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"placeholder.png"]];
```

Comment: pass as nil . if you dont need placeholder image .

Comment: getting error ----- UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:placeholderImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance  ----  for code ----- [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]
                          placeholderImage:nil]; ---

Comment: did you integrate SDWebimage to your project ?

Comment: Yes..using POD .. pod 'SDWebImage', '~>3.6'

Comment: Then import this file #import UIImageView+WebCache.h and #import "SDWebImageManager.h"

Comment: is any error displayed while you have import above file ?\

Comment: NO....even for ----  [cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:imageUrlString]]; --- giving error as ----- UIImageView sd_setImageWithURL:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance -----

Comment: I think it is the your pod integration issue see this : https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage/issues/885